Book from a Spanish academic researcher on the history of paper (or of books)
I am looking for a book from a Spanish academic researcher on the history of paper (or of books). I remember it had a plant on the cover.

Please revert the edits. I spent almost one evening looking for the answer, making a question and self-answering is totally acceptable on SE sites, I would liek to share the effort I did with the general audience.

@MattThrower please rever the question and self-answer to the question. In this site there is question that proposes a self-answer to a quite simple question (why did Melville include a lot of seafaring technicalities?= because he has been a seaman! https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/1427/why-is-there-so-much-technical-detail-of-whaling-included-in-moby-dick/1428 ) .
The book I was looking for is a very interesting one, but somehow neither the name of the author or of the book sticks to people's mind. Been there, done that ...

Ah, I understand what's happened now. You've reverted the edits yourself, thanks.

I’m voting to close this question because it does not appear to be about imaginative literature as defined in the help center. This is a question about history, not about literature.

@verbose do you not feel it qualifies as an identification request?

@MattThrower To belong on our site, the question must be about literature in the sense of imaginative literature. I don't see how a book about the history of paper qualifies. See this discussion.

@verbose this is a question about identifying a book discussing the creation of books. What can be a more suitable community of people, then (I am not referring to stack exchange page, that comes "automatically" afterwards)?

The book in question is Papyrus (original title "El infinito en un junco") from Spanish philologist Irene Vallejo.
It may be difficult to find this book with the usual Google search ... because searching a book about a book, or a book about paper, or other combinations yields nothing.
The search took me almost one evening, before realizing that pergament and papyrus are two distinct media, one animal-based and one plant-based ;) .

Pergament is usually called parchment in English.
